# Help with Entity Query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I can't seem to figure out how to write this query properly.  I've tried various combinations but nothing's worked yet.

Below is the relevant portion of my database model:
[image]

I need to select the products that match a given Category and Group, and that match a given Year, Make, Model, submodel.  This I've done below:

```
 ItemList = From P In gDataContext.Products.Include("Groups").Include("Groups.Category1").Include("LookupYearMakeModels") From G In P.Groups Where G.Category = Cat And G.Grp = Group  From Y In P.LookupYearMakeModels Where Y.Year = YMM.Year And Y.Make = YMM.Make And Y.Model = YMM.Model And Y.Submodel = YMM.Submodel Select P
```

I now also have to select products that match the Category, and Group but are Universal (Product.Univeral = True).

I'm currently writing two queries, the one above and the one below.  I'm merging the results of the two by simply using ItemList.AddRange(ItemList2)

```
ItemList2 = From P In gDataContext.Products.Include("Groups").Include("Groups.Category1") where P.Universal From G In P.Groups Where G.Category = Cat And G.Grp = Group  Select P
```

But I want to combine both queries into one and avoid merging the results.  How can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would stay away from using reserve words like Group as a name for one of my objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to set up a similar model, and I believe this works.  Here I am selecting products that have a group matching the given category and group and that have a matching year/make/model/submodel *or* are universal.

```
ItemList = From P In gDataContext.Products.Include("Groups").Include("Groups.Category1").Include("LookupYearMakeModels") 
           Where P.Groups.Any(Function(G) G.Category = Cat And G.Grp = Group) _
                And ( _
                        P.LookupYearMakeModels.Any(Function(Y) Y.Year = YMM.Year And Y.Make = YMM.Make And Y.Model = YMM.Model And Y.Submodel = YMM.Submodel) _
                        Or _
                        P.Universal = True _
                    )
           Select P
```

HTH

Comment: @mga911, great, glad it worked.  Does this mean I get the bounty :) ?

Comment: Yes and I marked your answer as the accepted answer.  If it didn't credit you the points yet then you'll probably get them when the open bounty period ends tomorrow.  Thanks again

Comment: I had to click on the bounty to award it.  I think you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***IQueryable.Union Method:***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx)

```
ItemList = (From P In gDataContext.Products                                 
                                  .Include("Groups.Category1")
                                  .Include("LookupYearMakeModels") 
            From G In P.Groups 
                Where G.Category = Cat And G.Grp = Group  
            From Y In P.LookupYearMakeModels 
                Where Y.Year = YMM.Year 
                     And Y.Make = YMM.Make And Y.Model = YMM.Model 
                     And Y.Submodel = YMM.Submodel 
            Select P)
            .Union(
            From P In gDataContext.Products                     
                                  .Include("Groups.Category1")
            Where P.Universal
            From G In P.Groups Where G.Category = Cat And G.Grp = Group
            Select P)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I'm looking for a way to make the two queries into one query not just merged the results.